# In an Odoo 16 QWeb template, the content of <link> tag is added after the tag, not within

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-16

I am seeing some strange behavior in an Odoo 16 QWeb template. Given the following template:

```
<channel>
  <item>
    <link>test</link>
  </item>
</channel>
```

[image: Template]

This produces the following output:

```
<channel>
  <item>
    <link/>test
  </item>
</channel>
```

Note that the content of the  tag is added after the tag, not within.
By simply renaming "link" to "url" (or any other string), the problem goes away.

Any idea how to fix that?